# I keep getting open() failed (2: No such file or directory) for old deleted files

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm facing a peculiar problem.
When I migrated my Wordpress blog from one server to another, database copy went fine but media failed for maybe 10% of the time. Since those images were 3 years old, I moved on. New site was working fine until I realized the following:

I checked my `nginx` error log `/var/log/nginx/error.log`and found lots of following:

```
open() "/var/www/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/thumbnail-new.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1
```

Now this file `thumbnail-new.jpg` is actually not available and it's not required anymore. So who's trying to access it? Search bots? Google?

I'm not sure.

But the problem is due to this error, my `php-fpm` processes are consuming a lot of CPU since most of them are waiting on an unavailable file.

What can I do? Please guide.

---

UPDATE 1

I checked with New Relic and all these requests are coming from search bots, Google bot, Bing bot etc.

[image]

And it's taking all my CPU
[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It absolutely normal, and can happen due to migration to other/newer applications.

Could you please share entire line, with 404 error, from access log? It have referrer link and actual url.

I would suggest to set 301 redirect for these kind of urls, process them before nginx passes it to upstream.

PS: Regarding cpu usage: nginx shell serve request with static file, instead passing it to php-fpm (usually). Could you please share rule that is responsible for static files serving as well? It would give whole picture.